# Sorting Json output in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Ive Created a web_service in PHP that outputs a JSON based in a MYSQL query. When invoked by my android app, the service returns the data to the app its converted to a JSONObject. 
Everything worked as intended because I sorted the data on the PHP server side, and the Android app kept the data in the samer order.

But when I was testing the app on lower APIS (Jelly Bean). I saw that the first record was a the bottom and the 2nd was first. I debugged that part of the code an saw this:

[image: messed order]

But when I debug the same part on newer API (nougat) I've found this:

[image: correct order]

I want to know if this is a bug or maybe I should change my java code on my android app. I thought the best way to sort the results was doing on the server side not the app side.

Here the code that reads the result of the web service:

```
 if (resultado_json[1].compareTo(URLSECCIONES) == 0) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resultado_json[0]);
                //Log.i("hola3", resultadofin);
                orquestador.procesarResultados(json);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you add some sort of id to this data so the sorting is always simple.

If using php just loop over everything and add a sortable id, or at least a date.

Since you do not provide backend code it is hard to say what you are doing, but in Java if you want to reverse sort something you can do this.

```
JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("records");
    for (int i = array.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) { //you are moving backwards, notice the i-- in the loop }
```

If you post your PHP code I may be able to help in that as well.

Comment: I opted for sorting the output based on an id and used the "Comparable" interface.